# Variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I call the function tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn, it returns 
Variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

My code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
PAD = 0
EOS = 1

sequence_size = 10 #vocal_size
input_embedding_size = 20 #length of sequence

encoder_hidden_units = 20
decoder_hidden_units = encoder_hidden_units * 2

encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, 
name='encoder_inputs')
#length of each sequence in the batch
encoder_inputs_length = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, 
name='encoder_inputs_length')
decoder_targets = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, 
name='decoder_targets')
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([sequence_size, 
input_embedding_size], -1.0, 1), dtype=tf.float32 )
encoder_inputs_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, 
encoder_inputs)

encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(encoder_hidden_units)
( (encoder_fw_outputs,
encoder_bw_outputs),
(encoder_fw_final_state,
encoder_bw_final_state)) = (
tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=encoder_cell,
                                cell_bw=encoder_cell,
                                inputs=encoder_inputs_embedded,
                                sequence_length=encoder_inputs_length,
                                dtype=tf.float32, time_major=False)
)
```

I got this as error:

```
ValueError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-41a8d71d81df> in <module>()
 23                                     
inputs=encoder_inputs_embedded,
 24                                     
 sequence_length=encoder_inputs_length,
  ---> 25                                     dtype=tf.float32, 
 time_major=False)
 26     )
 27 

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in 
bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw, inputs, sequence_length, 
initial_state_fw, initial_state_bw, dtype, parallel_iterations, 
swap_memory, time_major, scope)
348           initial_state=initial_state_fw, dtype=dtype,
349           parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations, 
swap_memory=swap_memory,
--> 350           time_major=time_major, scope=fw_scope)
351 
352     # Backward direction

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, 
sequence_length, initial_state, dtype, parallel_iterations, 
swap_memory, time_major, scope)
544         swap_memory=swap_memory,
545         sequence_length=sequence_length,
--> 546         dtype=dtype)
547 
548     # Outputs of _dynamic_rnn_loop are always shaped [time, batch, 
depth].

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in _dynamic_rnn_loop(cell, 
inputs, initial_state, parallel_iterations, swap_memory, 
sequence_length, dtype)
711       loop_vars=(time, output_ta, state),
712       parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations,
 --> 713       swap_memory=swap_memory)
714 
715   # Unpack final output if not using output tuples.

 /home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc in 
 while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, 
 parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name)
 2603     context = WhileContext(parallel_iterations, back_prop, 
 swap_memory, name)
 2604     ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys.WHILE_CONTEXT, context)
 -> 2605     result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, 
 shape_invariants)
 2606     return result
  2607 

 /home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc in 
 BuildLoop(self, pred, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
 2436       self.Enter()
 2437       original_body_result, exit_vars = self._BuildLoop(
 -> 2438           pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, 
shape_invariants)
 2439     finally:
 2440       self.Exit()

 /home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc in 
_BuildLoop(self, pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, 
 shape_invariants)
 2386         structure=original_loop_vars,
 2387         flat_sequence=vars_for_body_with_tensor_arrays)
  -> 2388     body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
 2389     if not nest.is_sequence(body_result):
 2390       body_result = [body_result]

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in _time_step(time, 
output_ta_t, state)
694           call_cell=call_cell,
695           state_size=state_size,
--> 696           skip_conditionals=True)
697     else:
698       (output, new_state) = call_cell()

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in _rnn_step(time, 
sequence_length, min_sequence_length, max_sequence_length, 
zero_output, state, call_cell, state_size, skip_conditionals)
175     # steps.  This is faster when max_seq_len is equal to the 
number of unrolls
176     # (which is typical for dynamic_rnn).
--> 177     new_output, new_state = call_cell()
178     nest.assert_same_structure(state, new_state)
179     new_state = nest.flatten(new_state)

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in <lambda>()
682 
683     input_t = nest.pack_sequence_as(structure=inputs, 
flat_sequence=input_t)
 --> 684     call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
685 
686     if sequence_length is not None:

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.pyc in 
__call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
336       # i = input_gate, j = new_input, f = forget_gate, o = 
output_gate
337       lstm_matrix = _linear([inputs, m_prev], 4 * self._num_units, 
bias=True,
 --> 338                             scope=scope)
339       i, j, f, o = array_ops.split(
340           value=lstm_matrix, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=1)

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.pyc in 
_linear(args, output_size, bias, bias_start, scope)
745   with vs.variable_scope(scope) as outer_scope:
746     weights = vs.get_variable(
 --> 747         "weights", [total_arg_size, output_size], 
 dtype=dtype)
748     if len(args) == 1:
749       res = math_ops.matmul(args[0], weights)

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in 
get_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, 
collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, 
custom_getter)
986       collections=collections, caching_device=caching_device,
987       partitioner=partitioner, validate_shape=validate_shape,
 --> 988       custom_getter=custom_getter)
989 get_variable_or_local_docstring = (
990     """%s

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in 
get_variable(self, var_store, name, shape, dtype, initializer, 
regularizer, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, 
validate_shape, custom_getter)
888           collections=collections, caching_device=caching_device,
889           partitioner=partitioner, validate_shape=validate_shape,
--> 890           custom_getter=custom_getter)
891 
892   def _get_partitioned_variable(self,

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in 
get_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, 
reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, 
validate_shape, custom_getter)
346           reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable, 
collections=collections,
347           caching_device=caching_device, partitioner=partitioner,
--> 348           validate_shape=validate_shape)
349 
350   def _get_partitioned_variable(

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in 
_true_getter(name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, 
trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape)
331           initializer=initializer, regularizer=regularizer, 
reuse=reuse,
332           trainable=trainable, collections=collections,
--> 333           caching_device=caching_device, 
validate_shape=validate_shape)
334 
335     if custom_getter is not None:

/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in 
_get_single_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, 
regularizer, partition_info, reuse, trainable, collections, 
caching_device, validate_shape)
637                          " Did you mean to set reuse=True in 
VarScope? "
638                          "Originally defined at:\n\n%s" % (
--> 639                              name, 
"".join(traceback.format_list(tb))))
640       found_var = self._vars[name]
641       if not shape.is_compatible_with(found_var.get_shape()):

ValueError: Variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/weights already 
exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? 
Originally defined at:

File "/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", 
line 
747, in _linear
"weights", [total_arg_size, output_size], dtype=dtype)
 File "/home/cesar/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py",      
 line 338, in __call__
 scope=scope)
 File "<ipython-input-23-f4f28501e56f>", line 24, in <module>
 time_major=True
```

Comment: Hi, being specific about what module you are using (ie. _Tensorflow_) and what exactly you are trying to achieve will make it easier to help you. Adding comments to your code (what does each section do) will make it easier to read as well.

Comment: Im using tensorflow 1.0.1 for  for a Seq2seq, using bidirectional layers

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem. I suggest updating to the current release of Tensorflow and letting us know if you still see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to define the encoder as follows:

```
with tf.variable_scope('encoder_cell_fw'):
    encoder_cell_fw = LSTMCell(encoder_hidden_units)   
with tf.variable_scope('encoder_cell_bw'):
    encoder_cell_bw = LSTMCell(encoder_hidden_units) 

( (encoder_fw_outputs,
encoder_bw_outputs),
(encoder_fw_final_state,
encoder_bw_final_state)) = (
tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=encoder_cell_fw,
                            cell_bw=encoder_cell_bw,
                            inputs=encoder_inputs_embedded,
                            sequence_length=encoder_inputs_length,
                            dtype=tf.float32, time_major=False))
```

It worked for me, this happens because the tf it is not managing to use the same name twice, bw an fw, another option would be defining with reuse=True but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:
insert tf.reset_default_graph() at the beginning of the block.
By running the script multiple times on the same graph, you are adding the variables to the graph for each run...